# How should I start to develop OneNote COM add-in with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, onenote

I want to develop a OneNote markdown add-in, but I don't know how to use Visual Studio 2015 to develop OneNote add-in.
I search on google and only found [Microsoft OneNote API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/onenote/onenote-developer-reference), however it doesn't has the tutorial to teach me how to develop with Visual Studio.
Can anyone help me find the development tutorial?

Comment: Have you ever used Visual Studio? This should be a prerequisite for that. Start with its templates.

Comment: Any reason it should be VS2015, by the way? VS2019 is the current version, and VS2022 is already beta.

Comment: @PMF I installed VS2015 earlier, and I also know how to develop console app in VS, I just find this [template project] (https://github.com/onenotedev/vanillaaddin) in github, but it only describes the outline, and does not have detailed details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.